# generating file using genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy

Hi i'm trying to work on python, and since i'm still a newbie ( but with great ambition :) ) i tend to have this error when I try to import a .txt file using the function np.genfromtxt() somehow it doesn't recognize the file, I made sure to specify the directory and everything but still getting the same error, if you could help that would be great thank you !

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
DATADIR = "wave_data/"
np.genfromtxt('signal_1.txt',delimiter=',')
```

Just so you know, wave_data is the folder containing all signal_i.txt files Here is the error :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-17c352b5ef2d> in <module>()
----> 1 np.genfromtxt('signal_1.txt',delimiter=',')

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise, max_rows)
   1547         if isinstance(fname, basestring):
   1548             if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
-> 1549                 fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU'))
   1550             else:
   1551                 fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rb'))

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.pyc in open(path, mode, destpath)
    149 
    150     ds = DataSource(destpath)
--> 151     return ds.open(path, mode)
    152 
    153 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.pyc in open(self, path, mode)
    499             return _file_openers[ext](found, mode=mode)
    500         else:
--> 501             raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
    502 
    503 

IOError: signal_1.txt not found.
```

Comment: It's not a matter of recognizing.  It's a matter of finding.  The directory is wrong. But that's not something we can check for you! You code sample tells us nothing about your directories.

Comment: If 'DATADIR' is the path to the directory containing your text file, try this : ```np.genfromtxt(DATADIR + 'signal_1.txt',delimiter=',')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is not in the current directory. Only you know where it is, but maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
fname = os.path.join(DATADIR, 'signal_1.txt')
np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter=',')
```

`os.path.join()` is the best way to compose paths from strings.